# C++ Vector Initialization List vs. Assignment

Tags: c++, vector, initialization-list

In C++ what is the technical difference between following two ways of initializing a vector?

```cpp
    vector<int> v_1 {0, 1, 2};

    vector<int> v_2 = {3, 4, 5};
```

The first one is an *initialization list*. What is the second one?

I appreciate hints on correct terminology and referring to documentation and different standard versions (C++98 vs. C++11).

Comment: The first is [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). The second is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Comment: No difference. This has been introduced to provide consistency in language syntax.

Comment: The first is an *indice* list. The second one isn't.

Comment: A decent compiler would generate the exact same code for both variants, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    vector<int> v_1 {0, 1, 2};
```

This is [*direct-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), a form of [*direct-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

An object `v_1` is constructed with the provided values.

```
    vector<int> v_2 = {3, 4, 5};
```

This is [*copy-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). In this case there is no difference from *direct-list-initialization*.

There is still a minor semantic difference, though, as *copy-initialization* excludes explicit constructors.

The list-initialization syntax (both version 1 and 2) was introduced in C++11.